# How to modify some parts of a CustomControl at design time in Silverlight?

Tags: silverlight, xaml, custom-controls, design-time

For testing purpose, I wrote a Silverlight custom control in a DLL, which consists only in a Grid containing a ListBox, **prefilled with 2 items**.
(FYI: In this project, I only have 2 files: BaseLayout.cs and Generic.xaml.)

Then, in another project, I put this custom control on my MainPage.xaml:

```xaml
<UserControl x:Class="Test.MainPage"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             xmlns:base="clr-namespace:Base;assembly=Base"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             d:DesignHeight="427"
             d:DesignWidth="508">
    <base:BaseLayout x:Name="MyLayout"
                     ListBoxBg="BlanchedAlmond" />
</UserControl>
```

I know how to change the background color of the ListBox using TemplateBinding.
I also know how to add items to this ListBox at runtime.

But is it possible to add items at design time, in the XAML?
Is there a way to allow something like this:

```xaml
<base:BaseLayout x:Name="MyLayout"
                 ListBoxBg="BlanchedAlmond">
    <ListBoxItem Content="Item 4" />
    <ListBoxItem Content="Item 5" />
</base:BaseLayout>
```

Any suggestions are welcome.

**EDIT:** To be more precise, I'd like to be able to add some items in my ListBox from two places:

- from Base.DLL, in Generic.xaml,
- from the other project, in MainPage.xaml.

And I'd like all these items to remain at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using mvvm, which means you have a viewmodel for your view that contains this `BaseLayout`, you can create a design time viewmodel, write your sample data in there and have something in your view like this,

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance design:DesignMainViewModel, IsDesignTimeCreatable=True}">
    <base:BaseLayout x:Name="MyLayout" ListBoxBg="BlanchedAlmond"/>
```

For more information, please see [this post](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff602277%28v=vs.95%29.aspx).

Also, you can create design-time data using Expression Blend. Please see [this post](http://openlightgroup.net/Blog/tabid/58/EntryId/87/Silverlight-MVVM-Enabling-Design-Time-Data-in-Expression-Blend-When-Using-Web-Services.aspx).

Comment: Yes, I'm using MVVM Light toolkit. And you fully understood what I want to achieve. I'll test you solution and come back for feedback. Thank you!

Comment: Hmmm... In fact, that's not what I want. I want the data I add at design-time to be still here at runtime.

Comment: @Rodolphe, then your title is misleading... what exactly are you trying to do? are you sure you need a custom control not a usercontrol?

Comment: The title was indeed badly chosen and I'm not sure about the custom control. I'll try to explain the big picture: I want a DLL containing a basic layout. This basic layout will contain a menu bar, a toolbar, etc. Then, in another project, I'd like to use this control on a page and be able to add some other controls in it, at design time and at runtime. But my problem is the menu bar and the toolbar must be partly filled from the DLL (with some classic items, like "Open", "Close", etc.) *and* from the page where I added my custom/user control (with specific items). Is it clearer? And feasible?

Comment: @Rodolphe, I think a usercontrol is a better candidate in your case. Here by design time you mean you can see the values in Blend's design interface, right?

Comment: Yes, I'd like to see them in Blend. And I also want them to be there at runtime. The more I read about this the more confused I get...

Comment: You should google how usercontrol works... you will need to create viewmodels for your usercontrols, and put some default values in the viewmodels so they will be shown at runtime, also you need to create design-time values, this can be done by what I wrote in my answer

Comment: I googled *a lot* and I'm still lost. I don't see how a usercontrol will bet better than a custom control. It just seems that what I want is impossible.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to achieve similar functionality as your example suggests, you could inherit from the ListBox and extend it. I haven't tried it, but maybe you'd be able to use the ListBoxItems in XAML as you show.

Comment: I used a ListBox here to keep my test simple but my goal is to build something more complex, with menu bars, toolbars and some panels. So I guess inheriting from a control won't do the trick.